# Check if time has crossed PHP

Tags: php

I have an app which should check that if Time is not within the required range then person should not able buy anything.

I am using PHP functions as below to check current time:

```
date_default_timezone_set ("Asia/Calcutta");  
$date =  date("H:i", time());
```

The time returned is correct but how can i check if time is in between 11:00AM to 11:00PM

Comment: It wasn't me so I'm just guessing: probably someone thought you did too little research. A short check on SO turns out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191867/php-function-to-check-time-between-the-given-range , which you may want to check out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using `DateTime()` for this as it is very readable (and deals with any potential datetime issues like daylight savings time but that doesn't apply here):

```
$datetime = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
$am       = new DateTime('11am');
$pm       = new DateTime('11pm');
if ($datetime > $am && $datetime < $pm) {
    // between 11am and 11pm
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/185634)